# Bootstrap is adding more icons than called for in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-rails

I am trying to add a user icon to my header. bootstrap is adding more icons than what my code calls for, what is going on? Thanks in advance!

```
<ul class="nav pull-right">
 <% if user_signed_in? %>
   <li><%= link_to "Edit Profile", edit_user_registration_path %></li>
   <li><%= link_to "Logout", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %></li>
 <% else %>
   <li><%= link_to "", new_user_session_path, class: "icon-user" %></li>
 <% end %>
</ul>
```

http://i.minus.com/i7krj72G9Gmsd.png

i am using the responsive navbar btw.

Comment: Have you checked the size of your links? Its possible the height is bigger than required and hence showing 2 icons.

Comment: I am not sure what the height of my links are nor do I know how to change it. My best guess is that its the default size from bootstrap.

Comment: Do you have a Fiddle or link I can view? Basically if you open up the Firebug or Dev tools and insepct your links, you can set the height or line-height to match the size of a single icon. Bootstrap icons are 14x14 pixels so if you set the height of your links to 14px, it should fit a single icon. You can add a class to your links and add the height in the CSS.

Comment: you can view the page here [link](http://still-tor-3256.herokuapp.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have the bootstrap icons in my rails project to test this, but see if this works:

```
<%= link_to raw("<i class='icon-user'></i>"), new_user_session_path %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set `padding:15px 15px 15px` to `padding:0` for `.navbar .nav>li>a` in your CSS.